# When to reference a fragment created in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager that sets up two fragments as swipeable tabs. I am trying to find these fragments in the hosting activity.

I set them up as class global variables:

```
private SharedBillFragment sharedBill;
private SeparateBillFragment separateBill;
```

and try to find them in the activity's onStart():

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    findFragments();
}
```

where findFragments() is (I know this is kind of a hack, but it should work for the moment...):

```
private void findFragments() {
    sharedBill = (SharedBillFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + 0);
    separateBill = (SeparateBillFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + 1);
}
```

But this is not working, the fragments are not found. When i call findFragments() in a method that is called later (following a user interaction), the fragments are found and I can use them. Example:

```
private void setCountryTip(String selectedCountry) {
    findFragments();

    sharedBill.setPercentage(getCountryTip(selectedCountry));
    separateBill.setPercentage(getCountryTip(selectedCountry));
}
```

But even when called then, the fragments are only available in the method where findFragments() is called, even though I set them as class global variables.

Best case, I would like to find the fragments when the app is started and store them in class global variables. Any help how to achieve that?

EDIT:
Some more information on how my fragments are setup. In my MainActivity I have:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] mTabTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mTabsAdapter);

    for (String tab_name : mTabTitles) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
    }
}
```

and my TabsAdapter:

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
final int NUMBER_OF_TABS = 2;

public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new SharedBillFragment();
        case 1:
            return new SeparateBillFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUMBER_OF_TABS;
}
}
```

EDIT: Regarding the NPE, my spinner is setup as follows in the fragment:

```
private Spinner spCountry;

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    spCountry = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spCountry);
    spCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
            mCallback.onCountrySelected(spCountry.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    ArrayAdapter spCountryAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) spCountry.getAdapter();
    spCountry.setSelection(spCountryAdapter.getPosition(country));
}
```

The spinner gets its entries via the xml property "android:entries".

Answer (score 0):

Not a very nice and re-usable solution, but since you are using static fragments it could work: make the adapters type Fragment, and initialize the fragments in the activity. Than add the two fragment to the adapter, and in the adapters getItem function only return the corresponding fragment.

Adapter:

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
List<Fragment> fragments;

public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    return fragments.get(index);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
}
}
```

Activity:

```
    sharedBillFragment = new SharedBillFragment();
    separateBillFragment = new SeparateBillFragment();
    List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(sharedBillFragment);
    fragments.add(separateBillFragment);
    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getFragmentManager(), fragments);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mTabsAdapter);
```

Find the spinner in the onCreateView like this:

```
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, containter, false);
   spCountry = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spCountry);
   ...
   return v;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am somewhat new to Android programming, hence I'm having troubles following you, could you maybe extend your answer with some code examples? I edited my question to show how my fragments are setup right now.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine! But when using this solution I get a NPE when calling a method in one of the fragments that tries to set a spinner. I do not get this exception when setting up the fragments they way I did before. Check the original post for how my spinner is setup.

Comment: Yes, it is because the view is not attached to the activity yet. Find the fragment in the onCreateView (edited my answer)

Comment: Just tried it and I still get the NPE. I'm calling the fragment method in the activity's onStart(), maybe that is a problem?

Comment: What kind of fragment method? And which line throws the NPE?

Comment: The method called in the fragment is setCountry(String country) (see original question) and the line that throws the NPE is the first line of this method: ArrayAdapter spCountryAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) spCountry.getAdapter();

Comment: Ok just confirmed that the problem lies with calling the method in onStart(). If I call it later (e.g. after a user interaction) it works fine.

Comment: Just call the setCountry after the Spinner initialisation

Comment: But how do I know in the activity when the spinner in the fragment is initialised? Obviously onStart() is too early...

Comment: Why would you want to know?

Comment: Otherwise I can't call setCountry after the Spinner initialisation (because I don't know when it is initialised). Remember, I am calling setCountry from a method in the activity.

Comment: Since setting up the adapter is a Fragment-specific job, you should move it there (so the setCountry should be a method of the fragment, and should be called from the onCreateView function there)